# Output of RasterToPolygon not supported as shapefile

Tags: python, arcgis-9.3

I made a python code for arcGis 9.3 which do the following step :

> 1) Convert all the raster (.tif) in a folder to polygon shapefile in
>   another folder
>
> 2) Intersect all the converted shapefile polygon (previous) with a
>   mask

The problem is that the intersect function doesn't work and it returns shapefile with no populate fields. 
So I try manually to use the intersect Tool with the converted polygon create by my python code. And I have this error when trying to put the converted polygon shape in input :

PolygonName # Does not exist or is not supported

And when I Copy/paste this same polygon in another folder, then it works.

My code is as following :

```
import sys, string, os, arcgisscripting, glob
import arcgisscripting
gp = arcgisscripting.create()

# Set a default workspace
gp.workspace = "Z:\PPR\PPR76\PPRI_AUSTREBERTHE\Modelisation_Ruissellements\Tentative Macro Amelioration MNT"

# Set a toolbox
gp.toolbox = "management"


pathImages = gp.GetParameterAsText(0)
pathOutputConversion = gp.GetParameterAsText(1)
pathOutputIntersect = gp.GetParameterAsText(2)
masque = gp.GetParameterAsText(3)

# ON CONVERTI TOUTES LES IMAGES DU DOSSIER EN POLYGON

for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(pathImages, '*.tif')):
    flnm = os.path.basename(infile)
    # Avec cette fonction : fileName contient le CHEMIN+nom du fichier sans l'estension et fileExtension contient l'extension (.qqch). Ici on voulait huste le nom du fichier sans le chemin donc on l'a applique a flnm 
    fileName, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(flnm)

    # Local variables...
    Input_Raster= os.path.join(pathImages, infile)  
    Output_Polygon_Features = pathOutputConversion + "\ " + fileName+ ".shp "

    # Process: RasterToPolygon...
    gp.RasterToPolygon_conversion(Input_Raster, Output_Polygon_Features, "SIMPLIFY", "")

gp.AddMessage(" FIN DE CONVERSION RASTER TO POLYGON ")

# ON INTERSECTE TOUS LES POLYGON IMAGES AVEC LE MASQUE DU BV

for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(pathOutputConversion, '*.shp')):
  flnm = os.path.basename(infile)
  # Local variables...
  Output_Feature_Class = pathOutputIntersect + "\ " +flnm
  Input_Features = masque +" #;"+os.path.join(pathOutputConversion, infile)+" #"

  # Process: Intersect...
  gp.Intersect_analysis(Input_Features, Output_Feature_Class, "ALL", "", "INPUT")
```

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is that you are joining paths with a single backslash (and putting a space after it). In python, the backslash is an escape character. Use forward slashes "/" or os.path.join to join paths (can also use raw string notation, i.e r'c:\Temp' but that doesn't work with single backslashes).

You also have a space after the file extension in `Output_Polygon_Features = pathOutputConversion + "\ " + fileName+ ".shp "`

Try this:

```
pathImages = gp.GetParameterAsText(0) 
pathOutputConversion = gp.GetParameterAsText(1) 
pathOutputIntersect = gp.GetParameterAsText(2) 
masque = gp.GetParameterAsText(3)

# ON CONVERTI TOUTES LES IMAGES DU DOSSIER EN POLYGON

# Set the workspace (to avoid having to type in the full path to the data every time) 
gp.Workspace = pathOutputConversion

for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(pathImages, '*.tif')):
    flnm = os.path.basename(infile)
    # Avec cette fonction : fileName contient le CHEMIN+nom du fichier sans l'estension et fileExtension contient l'extension (.qqch). Ici on voulait huste le nom du fichier sans le chemin donc on l'a applique a flnm 
    fileName, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(flnm)

    # Local variables...
    Input_Raster= os.path.join(pathImages, infile)
    #Remove spaces and path.join
    #Output_Polygon_Features = pathOutputConversion + "\ " + fileName+ ".shp "
    Output_Polygon_Features = fileName+ ".shp"

    # Process: RasterToPolygon...
    gp.RasterToPolygon_conversion(Input_Raster, Output_Polygon_Features, "SIMPLIFY", "")

gp.AddMessage(" FIN DE CONVERSION RASTER TO POLYGON ")

# ON INTERSECTE TOUS LES POLYGON IMAGES AVEC LE MASQUE DU BV

# Set the workspace (to avoid having to type in the full path to the data every time) gp.Workspace = pathOutputIntersect

for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(pathOutputConversion, '*.shp')):
    flnm = os.path.basename(infile)
    # Local variables...
    #Remove spaces and path.join
    Output_Feature_Class = flnm
    Input_Features = ';'.join((masque, infile))

    # Process: Intersect...
    gp.Intersect_analysis(Input_Features, Output_Feature_Class, "ALL", "", "INPUT")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! As you said it came from the "\" in path. Now i changed it using the os.path.join() ans it works perfectly. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You state that your error message has a "#" in it and the only line that has these is:

```
Input_Features = masque +" #;"+os.path.join(pathOutputConversion, infile)+" #"
```

Try this instead?

```
Input_Features = masque +";"+os.path.join(pathOutputConversion, infile)
```

Comment: Thank for your answer.                                                     I try it but it does'nt work. Actually it seems that it comme from the RasterToPolygon_conversion function because when i use the shapfile produce by this function in ArcGIS (Manually), ArcGIS write : # Does not exist or is not supported